# 'SuperGlobal' OOP variables for actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, variables, singleton

I am designing a flash website and I made it object oriented. I have a lot of classes and I am having difficulty in accessing information ( variables ) from other classes.

To do so I usually include the variable at the parameters of my class' functions ( or constructor) OR I create custom event objects that will transport the variables to another class ( that listens for them ). This methods are sluggish.

I know there are local variables ( those who are declared inside a function and are available only to that function ) and global variables ( who are declared inside a class as private or public and are available in that class ). Can I, somehow, create some sort of 'superglobal' variables that are available to the whole flash program?

If not, do you guys know a way to pass along variables in an OOP design?

Thanks! I will try to implement a singleton.

Comment: Explained the static class in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton class:

```
package {

   public class SingletonDemo {
      private static var instance:SingletonDemo;
      private static var allowInstantiation:Boolean;

      public static function getInstance():SingletonDemo {
         if (instance == null) {
            allowInstantiation = true;
            instance = new SingletonDemo();
            allowInstantiation = false;
          }
         return instance;
       }

      public function SingletonDemo():void {
         if (!allowInstantiation) {
            throw new Error("Error: Instantiation failed: Use SingletonDemo.getInstance() instead of new.");
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I think I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: You can also directly check the `instance` variable. So instead of having an additional `allowInstantiation` variable, in your constructor simply check `if (!instance) {...}`.

Answer (score 2):

Does NOT have to be anything like singleton. The solution is quite simple:

```
package sg {
    public class SuperGlobal {
        public static var vars:Array = new Array();
    }
}
```

Wherever you are in your code, you can access the *vars* array with this:

```
sg.SuperGlobal.vars["test"] = "Hello World!";

// somewhere else:
trace(sg.SuperGlobal.vars["test"]); // Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually one does this with a singleton class that holds some variables that can be used everywhere. Make one class for instance called "Environment", "Settings" or "Program", that holds some static variables, each class can then access these through Settings.soundIsMuted, for instance.

Comment: Wow. Never thought of that. A static class is a class that does not use a constructor? Also, do you think I should do that now that my website is advanced? Are those variables just "public var x"?

Comment: Could you point me to a tutorial? I know too vaguely to start using singletons.